# Why not synchronize run method java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a short course about Threads in Java, in one of my homeworks they asked me: ¿Why you don't should be synchronize the run method? show an example.

I searched about it, and that i think is use synchronized for a run method is not useful, at least commonly. Because the people don't call the run method manually, so the synchronized effect isn't visible creating multiple instances of a object with synchronized run.

So, i would like know if exist another reason or if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syncrhonizing the run() method of a Runnable is completely pointless unless you want to share the Runnable among multiple threads and you want to serialize the execution of those threads. Which is basically a contradiction in terms.

Comment: Thanks you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

If the `run` method of a `Runnable` were `synchronized`, then either

a) you have many runnables (in which case, no need to synchronise, as each one is called on a different object), or else

b) you have one runnable being called in many threads - but then they clearly won't run in parallel -- thus defeating the purpose of having multiple threads!

Comment: Thanks you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You may synchronize on run method, nothing wrong with it. I think the reasons behind this advice should be explained to you by the instructor of course.

- We need synchronization when there are shared resources (between threads).
- Synchronizing on a method is same as synchronizing on `this` which will block other method calls.

As a counter example, a poor man's Future implementation;

```
public class SynchronizedRun {

    static abstract class Future<T> implements Runnable{
        private T value;

        public synchronized T getValue(){
            return value;
        }

        protected void setValue(T val){
            value = val;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Future<Integer> longRunningJob = new Future<Integer> (){
            @Override
            synchronized public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    setValue(42);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        new Thread(longRunningJob).start();
        System.out.println("getting results");
        System.out.println("result = " + longRunningJob.getValue());

    }
}
```